# Get the original class if casted to its implemented interface

Tags: java, reflection

Assume a class as follows

```
interface Dummy{
}

class Funny implements Dummy {
}
```

Now I want to find a way to retrieve Class of a **Funny** object even if it is cast to **Dummy**

Comment: `foo.getClass()` `foo.getClass().getName()` ?

Comment: Why? If you put made a list of Dummy, then Dummy should be rich enough to use. Otherwise, make a list of Funny.

Comment: Or are you asking how to get it back to being a `Funny`? If so, then cast it: `Funny funny = (Funny) dummy;` *(after checking with `instanceof`)*

Comment: @NomadMaker  Assume that a lot more classes implement Dummy interface. If I end up with a list, say, List<Dummy> then I am able to figure out Class type of each list element easily using element.getClass() as khachik mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented this piece,

```
Funny fun = new Funny();
Dummy dum = fun;
Object obj = fun;
Class cdum = dum.getClass();
Class cobj = obj.getClass();
System.out.println(cdum.getName());
System.out.println(cobj.getName());
dum = (Dummy) dum;
obj = (Object) fun;
cdum = dum.getClass();
cobj = obj.getClass();
System.out.println(cdum.getName());
System.out.println(cobj.getName());
```

Received outputs as

```
Funny
Funny
Funny
Funny
```